# How to copy files from a SAS server to my local computer?

Tags: sas

I am trying to copy files from a folder on a SAS server to my local computer, I am trying to run the following codes connected to the server, and also disconnected from the server, but I am not getting positive results.

```
    infile '/SASPrueba/Prueba_ALH/Libro1.xlsx';
    file '/C:/Test/Libro1.xlsx';
    input;
    put _infile_;
 run;
```

```
%sysExec move "\SASPrueba\Prueba_ALH\" "\C:\Test\";
```

I would appreciate if anyone knows how to perform this copying.

Comment: Why use SAS to move files between computers? Just use your favorite SFTP tool.  Plus I doubt that you want to give write access to your local computer to the server. So run the transfer from your local computer and pull the files from the server.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time, the SAS server cannot access your local machine's disks, unless you've set up a network share, which is not the case in most settings.  You should instead use a network folder that both you and the SAS server can see, and place them there.

However, if you have access to Enterprise Guide, there is a task that lets you do this: the [Copy Files task](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2020/05/19/copy-files-in-sas-eg/).  It's built into SAS Enterprise Guide as of 7.13 (late 2017).

SAS Studio also has a similar option built in, "upload" and "download" in the Server Files and Folders tab.

You cannot execute either of these directly through SAS code, though - these are both point-and-click options.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use SAS to do this rather than using an SFTP tool as per Tom's suggestion, you could try proc download:

```
rsubmit yourserver;
proc download
  infile = '/SASPrueba/Prueba_ALH/Libro1.xlsx'
  outfile = 'C:\Test\Libro1.xlsx'
  binary
  ;
run;
endrsubmit;
```

Comment: Note that PROC DOWNLOAD is part of the separately licensed SAS/Connect product and also requires SAS running on both machines.